# VMware Converter MAC Adress

Tags: vmware-esxi, mac-address, vmware-converter

I want to convert a running machine to VMware ESXi with VMware Converter, but it assigns a random MAC address to destination virtual machine. However, in our network, port security and static arp tables are used, so there is no chance for assigning an IP address to an unknown MAC.

Is there a way of defining the MAC address of the destination virtual machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the VM's settings under each Ethernet adapter's settings menu.